# How to fix 'npm ERR! Exit status 64 ' error in npm

Tags: node.js, npm, server, json-server

I'm setting up a local server, and I am running my server with `npm run json:server` but I am getting the following error:

> **npm ERR! Failed at the jsonserver@1.0.0 json:server script 'json-server --watch db.json'.**

Can't figure out how to fix this?

I tried to update `npm update -g` and it doesn't help.
Also tried `npm i -g npm`
and install the json server locally using `npm i --save-dev json-server`
Doesn't help

````
    Lenovo-ideapad-990-95IKB:~/Desktop/jsonserver$ **npm run json:server**

    > jsonserver@1.0.0 json:server /home/zack/Desktop/jsonserver
    > **json-server --watch db.json**

    Could not find an option or flag "-c".

    Usage: pub <command> [arguments]

    Global options:
    -h, --help             Print this usage information.
        --version          Print pub version.
        --[no-]trace       Print debugging information when an error occurs.
        --verbosity        Control output verbosity.

              [all]        Show all output including internal tracing messages.
              [error]      Show only errors.
              [io]         Also show IO operations.
              [normal]     Show errors, warnings, and user messages.
              [solver]     Show steps during version resolution.
              [warning]    Show only errors and warnings.

    -v, --verbose          Shortcut for "--verbosity=all".

    Available commands:
      cache       Work with the system cache.
      deps        Print package dependencies.
      downgrade   Downgrade the current package's dependencies to oldest versions.
      get         Get the current package's dependencies.
      global      Work with global packages.
      help        Display help information for pub.
      publish     Publish the current package to pub.dartlang.org.
      run         Run an executable from a package.
      upgrade     Upgrade the current package's dependencies to latest versions.
      uploader    Manage uploaders for a package on pub.dartlang.org.
      version     Print pub version.

    Run "pub help <command>" for more information about a command.
    See http://dartlang.org/tools/pub for detailed documentation.

    npm ERR! Linux 4.19.5-041905-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "json:server"
    npm ERR! node v8.10.0
    npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! jsonserver@1.0.0 json:server: `json-server --watch db.json`
    npm ERR! **Exit status 64**
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! **Failed at the jsonserver@1.0.0 json:server script 'json-server --watch db.json'.**
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the jsonserver package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     json-server --watch db.json
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs jsonserver
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls jsonserver
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/zack/Desktop/jsonserver/npm-debug.log```
````

**Here is package.json:**

```
 {
  "name": "jsonserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "REST API Tracker",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "json:server": "json-server --watch db.json"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.14.2"
  }
}
```

Expected to start server on localhost:3000

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you're merging the idea of an npm run script with starting a [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) and haven't fully implemented either aspect. Here are the steps I would try, **assuming you wish to have a run script to start your json-server**:

1. **Rename `db.json` to `package.json`** since this is actually your `package.json` file for your node project. You probably created this file when you ran `npm init`. This file is not the json data that you're mocking for the json-server when you start the server with your custom script command.
2. Create a new file called **db.json** and *give it the mocked json you wish to use for your json-server*. For example, from the documentation:

**db.json:**

```
 {
      "posts": [
        { "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
      ],
      "comments": [
        { "id": 1, "body": "some comment", "postId": 1 }
      ],
      "profile": { "name": "typicode" }
    }
```

3. Now change your *custom run script command to **not include special characters***. For example, within your **package.json** change the following:

   `"scripts": {
       "json:server": "json-server --watch db.json"
     },`

**to:**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "json-server --watch db.json"
  },
```

4. Now *start your server with your custom script command*: `npm run start`. At this point there shouldn't be any errors for starting the server.
5. Now if you go to http://localhost:3000/posts/1, you should get the following json response:

`{ "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }`

Comment: Thanks for answering! Sorry I messed up db.json with package.json . So I actually meant package.json instead of db.json. I follow your instructions but still see the same error . Someone said to unistall global npm and install locally

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace located here: /home/zack/Desktop/jsonserver/npm-debug.log. Can you also please post your db.json file?

Comment: db.json https://github.com/ZackPashkin/node.js-localserver-for-crypto-tracker-android-app-/blob/master/db.json    npm-debug.log https://github.com/ZackPashkin/node.js-localserver-for-crypto-tracker-android-app-/blob/master/npm-debug.log

Comment: It does work on my other computer with same ubuntu 18.04! IDK,  maybe it was dependencies mess. Thank you, for helping me out!

Comment: I am glad it's working now! Your stack trace is complaining about the script cmd to start up the json server did you rename that within your package.json and try again?

Comment: Ok, I will try!